# ionic 2 not refreshing until click

Tags: angular, typescript, view, ionic2, ionic3

Sometimes when I dynamically load a list, or just bind some values, the view on the screen does not refresh until I click on the screen.

For example:
When the app starts, the list of friends is loaded in the background. The screen stays empty until I click anywhere on the screen and then the data instantly appears (it has already been loaded before, but just not shown). 
The same happens to a Popover where I have arrow keys to change the content of the Popover. Whenever I click the arrow-keys nothing happens until eihter some time (like 1 minute) passes, or I click somewhere on the screen.

Presenting the Value:

```
<ion-title>{{groups[currentId].location}} ({{currentId+1}}/{{groups.length}}</ion-title>
```

OnClick (same for left):

```
<ion-col><button ion-button full icon-only [disabled]="currentId===(groups.length-1)" (click)="onRight()">Next</button></ion-col>
```

Code for onRight

```
onRight(){
    if(this.currentId < this.groups.length-1)
      this.currentId+=1;
}
```

The ion-title does not refresh, until I press the "More" button (which does nothing else than navigating to another page).

Is this a known issue/ is there a solution for it?

Edit: ngZone fixed the issue. Thanks

```
onRight(){
  this.ngZone.run(() => {
    if(this.currentId < this.groups.length-1)
       this.currentId+=1;
  })
}
```

Comment: Some code example how you pass the data in the view?

Comment: I added the important snippets

Comment: Actually, ngZone mentioned in another post solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped @Thomas